# Limit of sequence using definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been asked to prove using definition of limits that limit of sequence $\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}$ is $0$.
But when proceeding as usual I am not being able to express $n$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Given $\epsilon > 0$, fix any integer $N$ satisfying $N > 1/\epsilon$. Then for all $n > N$ we have
$$0 < \frac{n}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose $n \over n^2+1$ as $n$ goes to infinity is 0 so for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N$ such that for any $n>N$ then $| {n \over n^2+1}-0|< \epsilon$ ,so we need proof there is always an $N$ exist,we simplified absolute value so we get $| {n \over n^2+1}|< \epsilon$ because $n$ is always positive we get ${n \over n^2+1}< \epsilon $ it is easy to see that ${n \over n^2+1} < {{n \over n^2}= {1 \over n}}$ so if ${ 1 \over n} < \epsilon$ the inequality is always true and finally we only need to set $N={1 \over \epsilon } <n$.

so for any $n$ with this condition the inequality i true , thus the limit of sequence is zero.